# Deploying changed files from repository?

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial, commit, production

I have tested both mercurial and SVN recently, and I fell for Mercurial to solve my version control needs. However, I have files in my repo, that I work on locally and commit my changes to daily.

I have yet not found any way to deploy files to a remote production environment from my local testing environment.

How can I do this and by "one click only" replace and/or update the files that have been changed from a mercurial repo?

I have FTP access to my production environment and, if that makes any difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can use `rsync` to copy over the changes from your working directory.
- You can use `hg diff` to generate a patch, or `hg diff -r <rev>` to generate a patch from a particular revision, and then apply the change remotely.
- You could make the remote end an hg repo and then push to it and update it.
- You could keep your local changes with `quilt` or `hg mq` and migrate those patches.
- You could just copy over the whole working directory, with replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Why not clone the code? using `hg clone my-source-repo` in your development location you get an updated state of your code.

Comment: Ok, but that recreates all files from the latest revision, which would be really not good if there's thousands in the reop

Answer (score 1):

When you don't need only the working copy without the repository, you can extract the committed files with `hg archive`.